# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: Mapping definition for [name_complete] has unsupported parameters: [payloads : true]

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I was working on a Django Project where I have 3 models. Student, University, Course. I set up the model, populated the database and trying to use `Elastic Search` for searching. 
So, I installed `Elastic Search version 5.5.0`. Here is the `Meta class` of my `models.py`.

```
class Meta:
        es_index_name = 'django'
        es_type_name = 'student'
        es_mapping = {
            'properties': {
                'university': {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'name': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'},
                    }
                },
                'first_name': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'},
                'last_name': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'},
                'age': {'type': 'short'},
                'year_in_school': {'type': 'string'},
                'name_complete': {
                    'type': 'completion',  
                    'analyzer': 'simple',
                    'payloads': True,  
                    'preserve_separators': True,
                    'preserve_position_increments': True,
                    'max_input_length': 50,
                },
                "course_names": {
                    "type": "string", "store": "yes", "index": "not_analyzed",
                },
            }
        }

    def get_es_name_complete(self):
        return {
            "input": [self.first_name, self.last_name],
            "output": "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name),
            "payload": {"pk": self.pk},
        }
```

`es_index_name, es_type_name, es_mapping` are defined in the top portion of the file like this:

```
import django.db.models.options as options


options.DEFAULT_NAMES = options.DEFAULT_NAMES + (
    'es_index_name', 'es_type_name', 'es_mapping'
)
```

To push all the data from the database to the index in bulk I have a command file named `push-to-index.py`. When I execute it by `python manage.py push-to-index`, it generates the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, mapper_parsing_exception', Mapping definition for [name_complete] has unsupported parameters: [payloads : true]')
```

So I looked up into the Google and found out that `payloads` is no longer supported in `version 5.5.0`. 
I found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/690), he wrote that he faked `payload` option like this:
`payload: { type: 'object', enabled: false }`. So I followed it but while doing so, I got another error saying `'enabled' is an unresolved issue`. And it won't work, the autocompletion of a name if I remove `payloads` from both the meta class and the method `get_es_name_complete(self)`.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You define the name_complete field to be used with a completion suggester, however you are using an unsupported parameter payloads [see documentations 17](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). So the fix is to remove that parameter.